# Redis-cli --csv option (exporting to csv)

Tags: redis

I would like to export a subset of my Redis data on the slave to a csv file.  I notice a new csv output option was added to redis-cli but I am unable to find documentation of how it works.  Enabling the option prints the command outputs to screen in csv format.  What is the best way to get this into a csv file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Cutting edge!

I've just looked at the [source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.0/src/redis-cli.c#L477-L511) & all it does is output the commands as comma separated values to stdout.  Which is no big surprise.

So you could just redirect it to a file, in the [standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file), as long as you're on Linux?

e.g./

```
redis-cli --csv your-command > stdout.csv 2> stderr.txt
```

Comment: how to import the exported csv?

Comment: @Boom Shakalaka - Please guide us here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321019/load-csv-file-in-redis-using-redis-cli-of-windows-version

Answer (score 8):

The command:

```
redis-cli --csv hgetall mykey > stdout.csv
```

created a CSV file like:

```
"id","value","id","value", ...
```

To make life **easier**, I used:

```
sed -i 's/\([^\",]*",[^,]*\),/\1\n/g' stdout.csv
```

which converted the output into:

```
"id", "value"
"id", "value"
"id", "value"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require wrapping the values in quotes as `--csv` does, then the raw output is sufficient, and you just need to join every 2 lines with a comma to get a CSV:

```
redis-cli <your redis command> | paste -d ","  - - > out.csv
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

Go to `src` redis directory and run the below command

```
./redis-cli $command > $file_name
```

Exemple: `./redis-cli SMEMBERS "$KEY" > $file_name(RANDOM NAME)`

this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case of socket and/or multiple redis servers, you'd need to do:

```
redis-cli -s /path/to/socket --csv your-command > stdout.csv 2> stderr.txt
```

E.g.

```
redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis4.sock --csv lrange my_list 0 -1 > stdout.csv 2> stderr.txt
```