# Export Redis hashes to csv

Tags: csv, redis

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368615/redis-cli-csv-option-exporting-to-csv) doesn't work for me

I run this command to find the number of keys that I want

```
SCAN 0 MATCH "test_user:*"
```

so I got a (very long) list of hashes that I want to export to CSV.

I tried

```
SCAN 0 MATCH "test_user:*" > list.csv
```

or simply

```
SCAN 0 MATCH "test_user:*" > list.txt
```

but always with syntax error response.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found is this (creating a sh script)

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern test_user:* |\
grep -e "^test_users:[^:]*$" |\
awk '{print "hmget " $0 " id display_name reputation location"}' |\
redis-cli --csv > test_user.csv
```

It works very well scanning for pattern, you can use regex for better accuracy.
Then you use a awk script to run the redis command 'hmget'.
Finally the output is printed in a csv file with the --csv utility

https://rdbtools.com/blog/redis-export-hashes-as-csv-using-cli/