# How to write a sequence of numbers to a text file?

Tags: bash, text, writetofile, seq

Beginner coder here :)

Writing in bash. I'm trying to write the numbers -7.5 to 72.5 in increments of 5 into the first column of a text file.

I can use

```
seq -7.5 5 72.5
```

to make the sequence of numbers

How should I write that into a text file?

Thanks

Comment: `echo "-7.5 5 72.5" > file`

Comment: `seq -7.5 5 72.5 >filename`

Comment: @MarkW That's piping operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux (Bash): Redirect all output to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842014/linux-bash-redirect-all-output-to-file)

Comment: @m0skit0, your command `echo "-7.5 5 72.5" > file` **does not** produce the desired results that Lily asked for! Please delete it.

Comment: @user3439894 No. It's a comment, and on-topic. If you do not agree with it, flag it.

Comment: @m0skit0 Please explain how it is on topic when it **does not** produce the desired results that Lily asked for, nor does it add anything relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect it into your file:

`seq -7.5 5 72.5 > my_file.txt`

Where `my_file.txt` is the name and path to your file.