# bash php silence segfault

Tags: php, bash, io-redirection

I need to prevent all php output, https://stackoverflow.com/a/617184/1695680 covers how to do this in general and for exception, errors, syntax errors so far it has worked, but.

php to produce a segfault in the pcre extension:
https://ilia.ws/archives/5_Top_10_ways_to_crash_PHP.html

```
<?php
# prce-bug.php

preg_match('/(.(?!b))*/', str_repeat("a", 10000));
```

In my testing, this still outputs:

```
user@host ~/crash-php $ php pcre-bug.php 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

user@host ~/crash-php $ php pcre-bug.php  >/dev/null 2>&1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So even with shell output redirection, output is getting to my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using a new `sh` shell instance will capture system reported process deaths, like Segmentation Fault and Killed.

```
sh -c 'php pcre-bug.php' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

However, input arguments do not go to php, but rather to the sh instance which does nothing with them.

Comment: I believe it is the shell which prints `Segmentation fault`, not the `php` process (which has already crashed). That's why redirecting the shell's output fixes it but redirecting PHP's has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Output redirection is applied to the process, however the segfault message is being generated by bash itself as a result of the child process dying with a segfault.

One solution would be to do something like this:

```
echo `php pcre-bug.php >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use compound commands `{ }`:

```
$ { php pcre-bug.php; } &>/dev/null
$
$ echo $?
139
```

From [Bash Manual -> 3.2.4 Compound Commands -> 3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) and `man bash`:

> **Compound Commands**
>
> **{ list; }**
>
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment. list must be
>   terminated with a newline or semicolon.
>
> This is known as a group command. The return status is the exit status
>   of list. Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are
>   reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be
>   recognized.
>
> Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list
>   by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

However, using `( )` doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
$ ( php pcre-bug.php ) &>/dev/null
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```