# bash redirect output to file but result is incomplete

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

The question of redirecting output of a command was already asked many times, however I am having a strange behavior. I am using a bash shell (debian) with version 
4.3.30(1)-release and tried to redirect output to a file, however not everything are logged in the file.
The bin file that I tries to run is sauce-connectv4.4.1 for linux (client of saucelabs that is publicly available in internet)

If I run

```
#sudo ./bin/sc --doctor
```

it showed me a complete lines

it prints :

> INFO: resolved to '23.42.27.27' 
>   
>  INFO: resolving 'g2.symcb.com' using
>   
>  DNS server '10.0.0.5'... 
>   (followed by other line)
>   
> INFO: 'google.com' is not in hosts file
>   
> INFO: URL https://google.com can be reached

However, if I redirect the same command to a file with the following command

```
#sudo ./bin/sc --doctor > alloutput.txt 2>&1
```

and do

```
#cat alloutput.txt
```

the same command output is logged, but deprecated as following:

> INFO: resolved to '23.42.2me@mymachine:/opt/$

It has incomplete line, and the next lines that follows are not even logged (missing).

I have tried with >> for appending, it has the same problem. Using command &> alloutput.txt also is not printing the whole stuff. Can anyone point out how to get all lines of the above command to be logged completely to the text file?

**UPDATE**

> In the end I manage to use the native binary logging by using --log
>   alloutput.txt where it completely provide me with the correct output.
>   However I let this issue open as I am still wondering why one misses some information/lines by doing an output redirection

Comment: What is the output of `cat -v alloutput.txt`?

Comment: @chepner : the output for cat -v alloutput.txt is the same like if the above binary is executed and shown in console, however there are some lines that are missing (as was described in the paragraph)

Comment: Another thing to try: redirect standard error and standard output separately: `./bin/sc > out.txt 2> err.txt`. I suspect a combination of `./bin/sc` outputting CRLF line endings along with the nondeterministic mixing of stdout and stderr.

Comment: @chepner I thought the same about possible CRLF. I checked with cat -e alloutput.txt | less
it returns me with each lines that ends with dollar sign, however the last line is chopped, without any dollar sign (and it does not proceed with other line). I will try also redirecting the standard error and standard output separately

Comment: @chepner splitting the stderr and stdout does not help either. in stdout, the last line is cut, and in stderr it is an empty file.. never even once have I seen this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a funny problem, I've never seen that happening before. I am going to go out on a limb here and suggest this, see how it works:

```
 sudo ./bin/sc --doctor 2>&1 | tee -a alloutput.txt
```

Comment: INFO: resolved to '162.222.75.243'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '192.168.2.1'...
INFO: resolved to '162.2me@mymachine:/opt/$   still is not working. it is really strange, have tried different methods, but still I do not see what might be the cause

Comment: I believe that it has to do with the program itself, on how it was built. If the native binary works, then the author probably anticipated cases like that and provided a solution. Still, it is very strange. If you can, try something else, just for kicks: store the result in a variable and then print the value: testVar="$(sudo ./bin/sc --doctor)"; echo "$testVar";

Answer (score 4):

you should try this: `stdbuf -o0`

like:

```
stdbuf -o0  ./bin/sc --doctor 2>&1 | tee -a alloutput.txt
```

Comment: Bingo, this is the reason for my case, the program didn't flush the buffer

Comment: Please explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
#commandtorun &> alloutput.txt
```

This command will redirects both the error and output to same file.

Comment: exact same result, the output.txt is incomplete. the same line is missing

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: @sjsam what kind of information should I also add? I just edit the original text with Bash version

Comment: @heike  : Actually, the comment was meant for the answerer. Single line answers don't provide much value in the longer  run. Regarding the question, may be you could mention whether `commandtorun` is a script or not

Comment: @sjsam  This command will redirects both the error and output to same file.

Comment: @learner : that information should have been added to the answer