# python logging: sending StreamHandler to file from command line

Tags: python, shell, logging

Let's say I have a script like the following, and **I can't edit it**:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()

logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug('debug log')
logger.info('info log')
logger.warning('warning log')
logger.error('error log')
```

later I call this script with:

```
python log_example.py > file.log
```

But it isn't populating the `file.log` file, but outputting the logs in console.

**Q:** Is there a way to, *despite configuring logging handler to StreamHandler*, still output the logs into a file from command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `&>` syntax, as in Pijnappel's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842014/linux-bash-redirect-all-output-to-file). This redirects all output (not just stdout) to the file.

```
python log_example.py &> file.log
```