# Compile contents of clipboard

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compiler-construction, clipboard

How can i compile the contents of the clipboard, i tried piping the contents  `pbpaste | gcc` but it did not work it gave the error **i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files** I  have heard that i can use temporary file with the command `mktemp` but I could not get it to work.

Comment: `gcc -xc -` should allow you do to that I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-xc -` will allow you to process `stdin`:

```
gcc -xc -
```

You can see a live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-94450d050c5d10ef3764e83d36569cb3).

Comment: I got this warning **i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: warning: '-x c-' after last input file has no effect**
**i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files**

Comment: @kylek There needs to be a space between the `c` and `-`

Comment: It won't compile anything it just freezes, my clipboard only contains a hello world program.

Comment: @kylek this works fine in the live example I linked and in my linux VM, so there may be something weird about the format of the data coming from the clipboard, is it in plain text? Maybe you can [redirect to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file) and see if that will compile and if not determine what about the format is causing the problem.