# C++ display output into php

Tags: php, c++, console

I have a C++ console application that returns some kind of things, then, I need to show that in a browser. So I tried to write every `console.write` from C++ to a `.txt` file for future PHP reading, but no success because it doesn't write the errors!

Then I tried to use `exec('program.exe', $output);` at PHP but no success too.. :/

- Is there another way to do that?
- Or any function in C++ that writes to a `.txt` every single thing that shows up in the console?
- Or some function in another Programming Language that catches everything in the console?

Comment: What was the problem with writting into file and reading from PHP?

Comment: And what the log file says?

Comment: btw. what about c++ cgi? You can directly use your program as a web app, if written in that manner

Comment: You know, he write the Console.WriteLine, but the errors don't. @RoyalBg, is a huge program, I couldn't write that again.

Comment: `exec('program.exe', $output)` is not sufficient. What is the rest of your solution?

Comment: What about some kind of stderr redirection? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that **cout** (standard output) and  **cerr** (standard error output) are two different streams, so probably you forgot to redirect **cerr** to your text file as well. Here some ideas you can use:

- Redirect your streams to a file on your code (see [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files))
- Redirect the output of any console program from the command line (you don't require to change the code and works on windows and unix / linux) by calling it this way `executable.exe > out.txt 2>&1`  (see [Redirect all output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file))
- Connect your web application to your console application using TCP sockets (might be an overhead but useful if the application requires some kind of interactive control)

Comment: Trying to use the second method output that to the .txt:
Exce‡Æo Sem Tratamento: System.IO.IOException: Identificador inv lido.

   in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   in System.Console.set_CursorVisible(Boolean value)
   in Butterfly.Program.InitEnvironment() at c:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Revision 5 - Alpha 3\Butterfly\Program.cs:linha 58
   in Butterfly.Program.Main() at c:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Revision 5 - Alpha 3\Butterfly\Program.cs:line 37

Comment: It'd be easier if you edited your question and added the relevant pieces of code (the code where you call your external application and the lines where the error appears)

Answer (score -1):

There are three standard file handles known as [stdin, stdout, stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). Looks like you're only fetching stdout right now. Try to redirect stderr to stdout.

```
exec('program.exe 2>&1', $output);
```

(works not only on *nix but also win32).

see also: [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Comment: Array ( [0] => 'test.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. )

Comment: Then test.exe is not within the search path. Try an absolute path like `c:\test\test.exe`