# redirection to file with '>' is not work

Tags: io-redirection, lsof

I want to redirect the result of 'lsof' to a file, but it does not work like this.

```
$ sudo ./lsof > result.txt
-bash: result.txt:
```

Is there anyone why it does not work?

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file). The output that is not redirected to result.txt is most likely written to stderr.

Comment: If it was stderr, shell would print it on console. Which it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because may be you do not have permission to wrote to file. Try following:

sudo lsof | sudo tee results.text

Or

sudo -s

lsof | tee results.txt