# Is there any console output type other than stdout and stderr?

Tags: unix, redirect, stdout, stderr

I run a a program in command line (unix/linux). But I need to get the results into a file. So i used.

```
program_name >> result.txt
```

But it didn't give anything to the file. Then I tried.

```
program_name 2>> result.txt
```

Then I got a portion of the results which was part of the `STD:ERR`.
But still some data shows on the console window. Is there any possibility to get that data to the file?

update:
I also tried

```
program_name >> result.txt 2&>1
```

I get all data except two lines. Why I'm missing that?

Comment: [Redirect all output to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file)

Comment: This question is different. '*command* > file 2>&1' is also not working. But 'script outfilename.txt' before execution of the command shows full output

Answer (score 1):

You can send stdout to file and then redirect stderr to the same stream (`&1`) like this:

```
program_name >>result.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: You mean some data is still sent to the console?

Comment: No this time nothing is showing in the console. But data is missing in the file. But when it is not redirected to the file, I can see the missing portion of data in the console

Comment: One more update is : when I use 'script oufilename.txt' before executing my command, I can see full data

Comment: Possibly the program is sending output directly to the console device `/dev/tty`  which bypasses the normal shell output streams.

Comment: Ok. Then how can I get it into some file? I'm a beginner

Comment: As far as I know there is no clean way to do this.  The best option is to modify the program - writing to /dev/tty is not portable.  Otherwise there is nothing better than a hack like using `script`.

Comment: This does not answer the question in the question's title. Does Linux have any other output streams apart from stderr and stdout? I am curious.