# Log anything in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I would like to log anything done in the terminal to be logged. Any given input and as well the output of that input. The command `history` will give you the inputs. I know how to redirect [outputs to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file) but i need a more general approach so that i can have daily log about what input was given and what the output was.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session

Comment: Most terminal emulators provide a logging facility, and there is the [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) command.

Comment: @augurar Thanks for the hint, but isn't that record on request? i want to have it always turned on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script` from [util-linux](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) can be used for that:

```
% script -q out_file.txt
% ls
out_file.txt
% exit
% cat out_file.txt
% ls
out_file.txt
% exit
```

See [`man 1 script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).

Comment: Can this be added to any startup of a terminal? and automatically saved with a date id?

Comment: @user1767754 You could try adding it to the bottom of your `.bashrc`