# How can I make this script work for all files in a directory?

Tags: ruby

I have this script where I can pull a string based on the line and position of it.
I got it working for one file, but how do I get it to work for all files in a directory.

Here is the code:

```
def pull_value(files, line_num, gbegin, gend)
   File.readlines(files)[line_num][gbegin..gend]
end

puts ("some/directory/file.txt", 10, 1, 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Dir.glob("*.txt")`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

There's "*.txt" argument mean *all files in the current directory with `txt` extension*:

```
def pull_value(files, line_num, gbegin, gend)
   File.readlines(files)[line_num][gbegin..gend]
end

Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |f|
  pull_value(f, 10, 1, 7)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can write the output to a file, instead of the console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file

Comment: Is there a way to turn the following into a method where the values are pulled, and written to a new txt file?