# Cronjob not process properly

Tags: sql, oracle, cron

I have created a script to gather stats on my oracle 12c database and given execute permission. Once i executed the scripts it works fine. But if i execute it through a cronjob it s not working as expected. Only the date of log file is updated and nothing in it as normal execution of the script. what would be the reason to fail the cron job

script and cron job as follows

```
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF

exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('SIEBEL');

exit;

EOF
```

cronjob

```
19 12 * * * /export/home/oracle/amalw/stat_gather.sh > /export/home/oracle/amalw/stat_gather.log
```

db.env profile is at /export/home/oracle  location

Comment: Why are you using cron for this? Please read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm#i1033533

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect the error output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674348/50552) to your log file with `2>&1`:

```
 19 12 * * * /export/home/oracle/amalw/stat_gather.sh \
     > /export/home/oracle/amalw/stat_gather.log 2>&1
```

Or tell `crond` to [mail you](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/) by adding to the top of the crontab:

```
MAILTO=you@gmail.com
```