# How to print the out put of dig command to a text file

Tags: linux, printf, dig

I want to print the out put of the dig command to a text file .

Comment: Did you try anything

Comment: dig_output =`dig -f | grep Answer | awk '{printf $1,$2}'`

#echo $dig_output >> dig_output.txt

Comment: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/56041), [Redirect all output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674327/608639), [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/876239/608639), etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any Command in shell can be redirected like this:

Example:

```
dig google.com > k.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. But how could i print only the needed parts. as TTL value