# Linux File Manipulation

Tags: linux, awk, pipe, tr, file-manipulation

I have been trying to manipulate a file using `tr` and have a task on removing all punctuation in one file and moving the contents into another.

```
cat file1 | tr --delete [:punct:] | cp file1 file2
```

When this command is used I'm returned with a preview of the file with no punctuation but when I look at `file2`, all the punctuation is still there.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what that script is supposed to do. Please provide concise, testable sample input and expected output to complete the required [mcve]. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: You didn't understand what a pipe (`|`) does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674327/608639), [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/876239/608639), etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is offtopic here but ontopic on the Unix se.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't changing `file1`, so the last `cp` just copies the old file. `cp` doesn't take input from `stdin` either, so you're not saving that translated output.

You can resolve this by piping your `tr` output directly into `file2` with a `>` redirect.

```
tr --delete '[:punct:]' < file1 > file2
```

Note that I've also removed the [useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: uuoc is contentious and of no relevance to the question. Performance wise the extra process is unlikely to cause a problem in this case and certainly isn't what original question was about.

Comment: @lain, Nowhere did I say it was better. I also linked to the post so they could read about it themselves. I prefer it without cat, so I make the change. It was also an afterthought in the post; chill out

Comment: Yeah, ok. I prefer the pure pipeline, reading left to right. It's easier to visualize and easier to build on.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need a redirect rather than a pipe. That last command is not reading stdio, just copying the original file1 to file2. Try:

```
cat file1 | tr --delete [:punct:] > file2
```