# Sqoop error logs

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am using IBM BigInsights Bigdata 4.1.0.0 for hadoop on RHEL 6.6. I ran sqoop import to impor t data from mysql to hive using following command :

```
    ./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/movielens --username root - 
    -driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --table movies -m 1 --hive-import
```

It is getting failed. Where can i check the log for it ?

Comment: The log should output immediately after that command

Comment: It is there but I cant read it completely as it is very big.I am using oracle virtualbox!

Comment: Then write it out to a file... `sqoop import .. 1> sqoop.out`

Comment: Its giving me permission denied error!

Comment: To create a file? You could put it at /tmp/sqoop.out

Comment: It is only able to capture warning for acumulo import.Not the whole error

Comment: Sorry, if you wanted the error, then use `2>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file#6674348