# What does redirection to file with ampersand(>&file) mean?

Tags: bash

What is the meaning of ">&file" in Bash? How does it differ from ">file"?

```sh
echo abc >&file
```

Comment: Here's a relevant answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file-in-bash).  In this specific case no difference (because echo doesn't use stderr - except in this case where abc ends up in stderr `echo abc 1>&2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash/876242#876242

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/637839/140750

Answer (score 1):

It's a bash shortcut for `> file 2>&1`  So fds 1 and 2 are both redirected to the file.