# How to use who command with a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

How can I use `who` command with a file I create?

I create an example file called `test.txt` with just random text in it, and using `who test.txt` file just does not print anything. Our teacher is asking us to use it on a file, but this doesn't give any output.

[image]

Comment: `who` displays who is logged in, not who created a file.

Comment: @0stone0 that's why I'm asking as well, teacher asked to "direct the result of it's execution to a file". I'm completely lost as to why I was asked that, when it clearly doesn't do what he's asking.

Comment: Seems like there asking to direct the output of `who` to a file, not run it on a file.

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Redirect all output to file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file-in-bash)