# How do I get the .write function to work with PyScripter?

Tags: file-io, io, pyscripter

To reproduce problem:

In the PyScripter editor, write:

```
outf = open('output.txt', 'w')
outf.write('hello, world!')
```

Result:

For me at least, here is what happens, when output.txt does not already exist.

1. `output.txt` is created
2. `output.txt` will contain no data or text at all when opened by any text editor.

So my question is, how do I make this work?

Other information:

I am using PyScripter 2.5.3.0 x64, with Python 2.7.3, 64 bit as the interpreter.

Printing to the console works fine, all other functions and code work fine.

When I use python in Command Prompt, I can write to output files fine. My problem is only in PyScripter.

Thanks,
DS

Comment: Have you tried appending `outf.close()`?

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you.

When Python is run from command line, it makes no fuss when you forget to use outf.close()... it still works fine. So I had gotten used to forgetting it, I guess.

Comment: Cool. I will provide you with complete answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was already resolved in comments, but I will post a complete answer regardless.

[Writes to files may be delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file). To make sure they aren't, force a flush by closing the file:

```
outf.close()
```

If you don't want to explicitly call close, try using `with ... as`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write('hello, world!')
```