# writing without closing in python

Tags: python, text, io, python-2.7, overwrite

i want to write to text file without closing because i don't know what i'll stop close,i'll explain the hole issue

i've create text called `resume.txt` , so after each specific processes in my project  it will overwrite in `resume.txt` so every time my project start it will check that file to know the last processes so my issue after each writing i have to close to apply it and i don't really think this is good i think there is better solution

this code will not work

```
wr = open('resume.txt','w')
login(usr,pas)
wr.write('login')
post(msg,con)
wr.write('post')
..so on
```

the issue is how to write without closing , i can't write the `wr.close` at the end because it might be terminated by the user or connection time out .. etc

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The `with` keyword is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you want to flush the buffer to your file? Have a look at [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file

Comment: if you want to 'see' your writes in the file as you write them, you need to `flush()` the file handle after each write.  this flushing of the write buffer is what is done on each file handle `close()`

Comment: tMC nice solution but it's not overwriting

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this applies to your code, but what about wrapping in a `with` block?

```
with open('resume.txt','w') as wr:
    login(usr,pas)
    wr.write('login')
    # This is hacky, but it will go to the beginning 
    # of the file and then erase (truncate) it
    wr.seek(0)
    # I think you wanted to do this after you tried an action, 
    # but you can move it to wherever you want
    post(msg,con)
    wr.truncate()
    wr.write('post')
```

This will ensure that the file is closed on error. When you want to close the file, just start your next code on the same level as with `with`:

```
with open('resume.txt','w') as wr:
    login(usr,pas)
    wr.write('login')
    wr.seek(0)
    post(msg,con)
    wr.truncate()
    wr.write('post')
    # wr.seek(0) ...

# Next steps...
```

I would also recommend checking out the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module to see if that can accomplish what you want.

Comment: Updating now - it is a bit/very hacky, but after each action it will reset the position to the beginning of the file and then remove the rest of the file. I don't know what your use case is, but you could also check out the logging (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, which can also handle writing to files.

Answer (score 3):

first of all i'd like to thank tMC

the solution is

```
wr = open('resume.txt','w')
login(usr,pas)
wr.write('login')
wr.flush()
post(msg,con)
wr.seek(0)
wr.write('post')
wr.flush()
```

i've used `flush()` to write and apply and `seek(0)` for overwriting

Comment: you could also re-open the file each time using the with block to ensure it closes.

Answer (score -1):

Try [the with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm). A little comlicated to understand, but should do exactly this.