# what can i do to optimize this function, and make it looks like more pythonic?

Tags: python, coding-style

What can i do to optimize this function, and make it looks like more pythonic?

```
def flatten_rows_to_file(filename, rows):
    f = open(filename, 'a+')
    temp_ls = list()
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        temp_ls.append("%(id)s\t%(price)s\t%(site_id)s\t%(rating)s\t%(shop_id)s\n" % row)
        if i and i % 100000 == 0:
            f.writelines(temp_ls)
            temp_ls = []
    f.writelines(temp_ls)
    f.close()
```

Comment: For starters, you could use `with open(filename, 'a+') as f:` to make sure that the file gets closed in case of an exception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.SE. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to use the `with` statement to make sure the file is closed properly. Also, unless I'm mistaken there should be no need to manually buffer the lines. You can just as well specify a buffer size when opening the file, determining [how often the file is flushed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3167494/1639625).

```
def flatten_rows_to_file(filename, rows, buffsize=100000):
    with open(filename, 'a+', buffsize) as f:
        for row in rows:
            f.write("%(id)s\t%(price)s\t%(site_id)s\t%(rating)s\t%(shop_id)s\n" % row)
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things that come to mind immediately:

1. Use a `with` statement, rather than manually closing your file.
2. Pass a generator expression to `f.writelines` rather than building up a 100000 row list over and over (let the standard library handle how much, if any, it buffers the output).
3. Or, better yet, use the `csv` module to handle writing your tab-separated output.

Here's a quick stab at some improved code:

```
from csv import DictWriter

def flatten_rows_to_file(filename, rows):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as f:
        writer = DictWriter(f, ['id','price','site_id','rating','shop_id'],
                            delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Note that if you're using Python 3, you need slightly different code for the opening the file. Use mode `'a'` rather than `'ab'` and add the keyword argument `newline=""`. You didn't need the `+` in the mode you were using (you are only writing, not writing and reading both).

If the values in your `rows` argument may have extra keys beyond the ones you were writing, you'll need to pass some extra arguments to the `DictWriter` constructor as well.

Comment: If the rows is larger than a 1G or more? And your computer memory is only 1G.

Comment: @user2000477: Is `rows` some kind of generator then? If not, you'll already have run out of memory before the code ever runs. If it is a generator, either `f.writelines` or `csv.DictWriter.writerows` will do the right thing, keeping only the data for a single line in memory while it is being written. They essentially do the loop in tobias_k's answer (though in C code, so probably faster).