# Why the flush() in python not clearing the whole text file?

Tags: python

the output:

```
Before flush():
 He

After flush():
 llo World !
```

why the fileobject not clearing the whole gfg.txt while I am making it read only two char on the txt file why does that have an impact on not cleaning the whole file?

```
# program to demonstrate the use of flush()
 
# creating a file
fileObject = open("gfg.txt", "w+")
 
# writing into the file
fileObject.write("Hello World !")
 
# closing the file
fileObject.close()
 
 
# opening the file to read its content
fileObject = open("gfg.txt", "r")
 
# reading the contents before flush()
fileContent = fileObject.read(2)
 
# displaying the contents
print("\nBefore flush():\n", fileContent)
 
 
# clearing the input buffer
fileObject.flush()
 
# reading the contents after flush()
# reads nothing as the internal buffer is cleared
fileContent = fileObject.read()
 
# displaying the contents
print("\nAfter flush():\n", fileContent)
 
# closing the file
fileObject.close()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you think calling `flush` on a read only stream does?

Comment: Because the purpose of `flush` is not anything at all related to what you seem to expect. I can't tell you why you don't get the result you expect, because I can't understand why you expect it.

Comment: The purpose of flush is for OUTGOING data (i.e. a file opened in write mode), not INCOMING data (a file opened in read mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `flush` on a read only stream does nothing.

Quoting the documentation for  [`io.IOBase.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush):

> Flush the write buffers of the stream if applicable. This does nothing for read-only and non-blocking streams.

The point of `flush` is to flush an *output* buffer, where writes are queued up in memory before actual file I/O is performed. It doesn't have any use for input streams.

It also doesn't change the position of the stream, to the end or otherwise. If you want to move the stream position, use [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek).

See also [What is the use of buffering in python's built-in open() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712601/11082165)