# Writing a file every x seconds from a function python

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a text file every 5 seconds from the data that is being created by this code.

```
import time
x = 0
while x < 60:
    x += 1
    y = x + 2
    print(x,y)
    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        f = open("outputtest.txt", "a+")
        f.write(str(x) + "\n")
        time.sleep(5)
```

What I basically want it to do is print the x value of the script every 5 seconds to a data file

Edit: Data is not being outputted to a file currently and that is what i am trying to figure out how to do.

the output would ideally be 
5
10
15
20
etc

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Is there something wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: What is the data being created by this code? Numbers 1 to 59? What is `y` for?

Comment: The data does not get outputted to the text file.

Comment: The data being created is just a test in order to see if I can do it. What my actual goal is going to be outputting a voltage from a digital to analog converter from a raspberry pi. X in this case is just a variable and will be later inputted as voltage

Answer (score 0):

If your file operations going to take a long time before closing the file, you should considering to force the write operation by calling the [flush](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm) methode of the file object. This will write several bufferd data to the file.

See also: [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)