# seek. function without output

Tags: python, file, seek

```
 tips_file = open('code_tips.txt', 'w+')
 tips_file.write('-use simple function and variable names\n-comment code\n-organize code into functions\n')
 tips_file.seek(0)
 tips_text = tips_file.read()
 print (tips_text)
```

There is no output for the above code.
But for the following codes, there is output

```
tips_file.seek(13)
tips_text = tips_file.read()
print(tips_text)
```

I am wondering why there is difference

I just figure out that if I separate the code into 2 cells

```
tips_file = open('code_tips.txt', 'w+')
tips_file.write('-use simple function and variable names\n-
commentcode\n-organize code into functions\n')
```

and

```
tips_file.seek(0)
tips_text = tips_file.read()
print(tips_text)
```

Then I can deliver output if I run the first cell once and the second cell twice. If only run the second cell for once, it gives no output as the same of the problem. I am really confused.

Comment: I get some output with your first snippet

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file