# Python after sending a file to a remote client the file finishes writing a lot longer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

s is a standard tcp socket,this is the server:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5203))
with open("example.txt" "wb+") as f:
exqwrt = f.read(1024)
while (exqwrt):
    s.send(exqwrt)
    exqwrt = f.read(1024)
```

code on client is, s is a standard tcp socket as well:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5203))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
openedFile = open("examplet.txt", "wb+")
while True:
    exwqrt = conn.recv(1024)
    openedFile.write(exqwrt)
    if not exqwrt:
        break
```

The problem is that file gets sent pretty fast.But it is written on examplet.txt pretty slowly in like 5 minutes.

Comment: You're not flushing the contents to the file so I assume it could be stuck in the buffer.

Comment: Try closing the 3 sockets when you are done with them. Does that make it faster?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't know what that means

Comment: @tdelaney will try it

Comment: @jianu81 data isn't written instantly to a file that you haven't closed. It's buffered up and written in blocks. Since you don't call `.close()` on the file, it's possible that the data is being queued for writing and it takes 5 minutes for enough data to be received to actually do a write to the file.

Comment: I ran your script successfully. It had several errors hinting that the failing script is something different. Have you run this code exactly and does it fail?

Comment: @roganjosh you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)

Comment: First note that duplicates are not bad things. I had to take a stab on my initial answer. I think that link includes all the info needed to answer this. It's not necessarily closing the file to flush the buffer, which might not be ideal for a client; the other ways are covered there.