# write values into csv during script execution

Tags: python

I have a simple script that reads values from one csv, runs some internal function on them that takes 2-3 seconds each time, and then writes the results into another csv file.

Here is what it looks like, minus the internal function I referenced.

```
import csv
import time

pause = 3

with open('input.csv', mode='r') as input_file, \
     open('output.csv', mode='w') as output_file:
    input_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                               quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    count = 1
    for row in input_reader:
        row['new_value'] = "result from function that takes time"
        output_writer.writerow( row.values() )
        print( 'Processed row: ' + str( count ) )
        count = count + 1
        time.sleep(pause)
```

The problem I face is that the `output.csv` file remains blank until everything is finished executing.

I'd like to access and make use of the file elsewhere whilst this long script runs.

Is there a way I can prevent the delay of writing of the values into the `output.csv`?

Edit: here is an dummy csv file for the script above:

```
value
43t34t34t
4r245r243
2q352q352
gergmergre
435q345q35
```

Comment: Have you thought of creating a string object which you append (write to) the new rows, which you then later write to the file?

Comment: Putting an `output_file.flush()` after the `output_writer.writerow()` call might do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look at the [buffering](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) option - this is what controls how often Python flushes to a file.

Specifically setting `open('name','wb',buffering=0)` will reduce buffering to minimum, but maybe you want to set it to some thing else that makes sense.

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1
>   to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no
>   buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as
>   follows:
>
> - Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying
>     device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On
>     many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
> - “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use line buffering. Other text files use the policy described above
>     for binary files.

See also [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file#3168436) .