# Empty file by using serial.readline() in the main loop

Tags: python, readline, pyserial

I've been trying to send the data I am receiving from a serial port. I'm reading the ASCII data from my device by using the `serial.readline()`. When I use this function in the main loop, I can print the string but I cannot send it to my output file. My `f.write()` function is not working when I place the `readline()` in the loop. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
import serial
import csv
ser=serial.Serial('COM6', 9600, 8, parity='N', timeout=2)
with open('output.csv','a') as f:
    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        if line:
            print(line)
            f.write(line)
```

This is the data I get, but nothing in the output file.

```
0R5,Th=24.3C,Vs=24.2V
0R2,Ta=23.3C,Ua=21.3P,Pa=1026.9H
0R1,Dm=000#,Sm=99.9#
0R5,Th=24.3C,Vs=24.2V
```

Comment: Please, fix the indentation - I guess the whole `while loop` needs to be indented by one level. i,e, if your code do look like this you will get IndentationError

Comment: Yes, my error when placed the code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File will be flushed when buffer if full and closed when you exit `with` block.
If you stay in loop forever no changes in file will not be seen until buffer is filled.

You can change buffering on output file. See [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)

In your example you could use

```
with open('output.csv', 'a', buffering=0) as f:
```

Comment: Great! It solved my problem. I am able to send the data to my output file. Thanks!