# How can I convert a Pyspark dataframe to a CSV without sending it to a file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I need to convert to a CSV file, and then I need to send this CSV to an API. As I'm sending it to an API, I do not want to save it to the local filesystem and need to keep it in memory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy way:** convert your dataframe to Pandas dataframe with `toPandas()`, then save to a string. To save to a string, not a file, you'll have to call `to_csv` with `path_or_buf=None`. Then send the string in an API call.

From [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation:

> Parameters
>
> path_or_bufstr or file handle, default None
>
> File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a string.

So your code would likely look like this:

```
csv_string = df.toPandas().to_csv(path_or_bufstr=None)
```

**Alternatives:** use [tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) with a large buffer to create an in-memory file. Or you can even use a [regular file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), just make your buffer large enough and don't flush or close the file. Take a look at [Corey Goldberg's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168436/1958151) of why this works.

Comment: It looks like the argument name is actually `path_or_buf`. Works like a charm after making that change

Comment: Agree with Josh, `path_or_buf` seems to be the current parameter's name. Plus, converting to pandas adds a index column automatically. Being said that, my code is `csv_string = df.toPandas().to_csv(path_or_buf=None, index=False)`

Hope it helps