# How to split a Pyspark dataframe while limiting the number of rows?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am sending data from a dataframe to an API that has a limit of 50,000 rows. Say my dataframe has 70,000 rows, how can I split it into separate dataframes, each with a max row count of 50,000? These do not have to be even and the data order does not matter.

Comment: u could a condition using `df.count` and do if greater than 50k use `randomSplit` function. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit

Comment: something like

 `def split(df):
    if df.count()>50000:
        df1,df2=df.randomSplit([0.5,0.5],24)
        return df1,df2
    else:
        return df`

Comment: Josh, you might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958225/split-spark-dataframe-into-two-dataframes-70-and-30-based-on-id-column-by-p)

Comment: @Josh a better solution would be to leverage `foreachPartition` method on dataframes, in this way you can control the exact number of rows per partition and send the data directly to your API as you previously asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645936/how-can-i-convert-a-pyspark-dataframe-to-a-csv-without-sending-it-to-a-file.

Comment: Another workaround for this can be to use `.limit()` function. 
You can do something like:
let's say your main df with 70k rows is original_df. 
So you can do like `limited_df = df.limit(50000)` for the very first time to get the 50k rows and for the next rows you can do `original_df.subtract(limited_df)` and you will get the remaining rows. You can even do .limit() for the subtracted df too if needed.

Comment: @frosty This is the best way to go I think as I can repeatedly do this until the dataframe is under 50,000 rows.

Comment: You can do it for any number of rows present in dataframe. Let's say at one point if your dataframe has 30000 rows and if you did df.limit(50000), it's not gonna throw any error and will just return the 30k rows present in dataframe.

Comment: @frosty Right, this is a good solution. I was able to use a while loop to batch up some datasets that had over 300k rows into 50k sets perfectly. You should post this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround for this can be to use `.limit()` function. You can do something like: let's say your main df with 70k rows is original_df. So you can do like

```
limited_df = df.limit(50000)
```

for the very first time to get the 50k rows and for the next rows you can do

```
original_df.subtract(limited_df)
```

and you will get the remaining rows. You can even do .limit() for the subtracted df too if needed.

**UPDATED:**
You can do it for any number of rows present in dataframe. Let's say at one point if your dataframe has 30000 rows and if you did df.limit(50000), it's not gonna throw any error and will just return the 30k rows present in dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the following by using row_number and then splitting for every 50000 rows

```
#order by any column to populate the row number
window=Window.orderBy('ID')
length=df1.count()
df2=df1.withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(window))

step=50000
for i in range(1,length,step):
    df3 = df2.filter((f.col('row')>=i) & (f.col('row')<=i+step-1))
    #Here perform your API call as it will contain only 50000 rows at one time
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition on @frosty his answer:

```
limited_df = df.limit(50000).cache()
rest_df = original_df.subtract(limited_df)
```

`.cache()` is advised for consistency, because without it `limited_df` and `rest_df` can have overlapping rows. That behaviour is due to PySpark running `.limit()` distributed and multiple times (once for `limited_df` and once for `rest_df`).

<sup>p.s. reason for separate answer: I couldn't comment yet.</sup>