# Python write and read random numbers to file

Tags: python, list, read-write

I'm writing a Python code to write random files to a file and read the same numbers from the file and put them to an int list

```
import random
import datetime

w = open("test.txt", "w")
for n in range(0,2):
    w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))
    w.write(",")
w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))

f = open("test.txt", "r")
myArray = f.read().split(',')
for i in range (0,len(myArray)):
    myArray[i] = int(myArray[i])

print(myArray)
```

But when I run the code, I get error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                                         
    myArray[i] = int(myArray[i])                                                                                                               
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How can I solve this? Is there any other way to write random numbers to a file and then put them to a list?

Answer (score 4):

The error is, that you don't close the file after writing into it. So there is nothing written. One solution is to use context manager (`with` keyword) that automatically closes the file:

```
import random
import datetime

with open("test.txt", "w") as w:
    for n in range(0, 2):
        w.write(str(random.randint(0, 10000)))
        w.write(",")
    w.write(str(random.randint(0, 10000)))

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    myArray = f.read().split(",")

for i in range(0, len(myArray)):
    myArray[i] = int(myArray[i])

print(myArray)
```

Prints:

```
[3998, 6615, 7496]
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have a better time using a machine-readable format such as JSON:

```
import random
import json

numbers = [random.randint(0, 10000) for x in range(3)]

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    json.dump(numbers, f)

# ...

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    numbers = json.load(f)

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to close the file after writing and before reading. Else you will be reading an empty file. Best way to do this is to use file as a context manager.

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as w:
    for n in range(0, 2):
        w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))
        w.write(",")
    w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    myArray = list(map(int, f.read().split(',')))

print(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush what you wrote to the file. When the file is closed it is flushed automatically. Using `with` could avoid calling close manually:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as w:
    for n in range(0,2):
        w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))
        w.write(",")
    w.write(str(random.randint(0,10000)))
```

reference:
[How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can ry changing this part:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
myArray = f.read().split(',')
for i in range (0,len(myArray)):
    myArray[i] = int(myArray[i])
```

to:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
myArray = f.read().split(',')
myArray = list(map(int, filter(None, myArray)))
```

Using the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method can filter out empty strings, and the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method maps every element in the give iterator with the given function.