# How can I stop a function from writing to a textfile before it's meant to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am programming a connect 4 genetic algorithm, and I want to save certain games to a text file. When I tried doing this I was having severe formatting issues and I managed to recreate the error in the following code:

```
def write():

    with open("saved_games.txt", "a") as text_file:

        text_file.write("c")


with open("saved_games.txt", "a") as text_file:

    text_file.write("a")
    text_file.write("b")
    write()
    text_file.write("d")
```

the textfile looks like this after the program is run:
`cabd`. I expected it to say `abcd`. It is clear that for some reason the function which is defined but not called before a and b are written is somehow activating and writing to the text file before it is called.

I don't know if this would help solve the problem, but the file must be in append mode because I have to be able to add multiple games to it without overwriting other stuff as with write mode.

How can I fix this issue, and make the program write abcd to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because writing to a file is an expensive operation, so python actually writes to a buffer. When the buffer fills up ([it's slightly more complicated than that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)), or when the file handle is closed, the buffer is flushed to the filesystem.

In your case, this is what that looks like:

```
with open("saved_games.txt", "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write("a") # ----> text_file buffer = a
    text_file.write("b") # ----> text_file buffer = ab
    write()              # -------------> Open a new file handle, write c, close it

    # At this point, file contents: c
    text_file.write("d") # ----> text_file buffer = abd

# Exit the with block, write buffer contents to file
# File contents: cabd
```

You can manually `flush()` the file before calling the other function to force it to write `ab` to the file before it writes `c`.

```
def write():
    with open("saved_games.txt", "a") as text_file2:
        text_file2.write("c")


with open("saved_games.txt", "a") as text_file1:
    text_file1.write("a") # ---> text_file1 buffer = a
    text_file1.write("b") # ---> text_file1 buffer = ab
    text_file1.flush()    # ---> text_file1 buffer cleared
    # File contents: ab
    write()  # ---> Open, write c, close file. File contents: abc
    text_file1.write("d") # ---> text_file1 buffer = d

# Exit with block. Write buffer to file
# File contents: abcd
```

The output is now:

```
abcd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for explaining it to me! I'll be sure to accept it once StackOverflow lets me.