# Seeing the progress of my code in real time in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I have this code which I am running on jupyter notebook

```
with open('tracker.txt', 'w+') as p:
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        p.write("\nValue is: "+str(i) )
```

while running this code when I am opening the `tracker.txt` file it is showing my blank, and only showing the result after the code is executed completely. But I want to see the results getting printed in the file in real time so that I can track the progress of the code. I am not able to get how to achieve that. Any help will be great.

Comment: Call `p.flush()` after `p.write(...)` inside the loop.

Comment: See also: [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)

Comment: Take a copy of your output file. It will show you where things are at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `p.flush()` after `p.write(...)` inside the loop.

```py
with open('tracker.txt', 'w+') as p:
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        p.write("\nValue is: {}".format(i) )
        p.flush()
```

See also: [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)